# Use an ARM template to create a database by copying another, only if the target database does not already exist

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm using an ARM template to provision an Azure SQL database. I'd like to say that *if* this database doesn't already exist, it should be created by copying another, fixed, database. But *if* my desired database *does* already exist, it should be left alone.

The functionality of 'only do something if the current state is not the desired state' is the standard functionality of deployments in `Incremental` mode. But it seems that this doesn't go well with a `createMode` of `Copy`.

I have template JSON that looks like this (never mind the absence of parameterisation, this is an example):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
      "name": "[myservername/mydatabasename]",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
      "location": "[UK South]",
      "properties": {
        "createMode": "Copy",
        "sourceDatabaseId": "[redacted]/myservername/databases/mysourcedatabase",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The first deployment succeeds, as expected. But if the same deployment is repeated, an error is obtained:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 11:51:49 - Resource Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases 'myservername/mydatabasename' failed with message '{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "The destination database name 'mydatabasename' already exists on the server 'myservername'.",
  "target": null,
  "details": [],
  "innererror": []
}'
```

If I use `createMode` `Default`, then I can repeat the deployment and it is idempotent, but I can't specify that the initial creation should be by copying `mysourcedatabase`.

Short of doing horrible things with `condition` and `resourceId`, is there any way I can say "create-by-copying *or* do nothing" ?

Comment: it seems like database copy mode is the exception to the rule that arm templates imperatively declare which resources should exists,  ... or just an overseen bug by MS ... it nags me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cant do that even with `conditions` and `resourceId()`, at least not without some hacks. Easiest way - use external entity to decide if this deployment is needed and pass in appropriate parameter.